# Export Contacts to Google contacts

Tags: contacts, xiaomi, google-contacts

I suddenly understand that the Contacts I registered the last months didn't be included in Google contact but in MI contacts. 
I use a MI MAX 2 PHONE with Android 7.1 version of Android.

How can I get all these contacts in Google contacts?
I didn't find the way

Comment: See if those can be exported to  excel or vcf and from laptop you can import them into your Google account. They're posts describing how to do that

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. There's no solution without laptop?

Comment: I am not aware of any apps can do that for your device. Search on your device forums

Answer (score 1):

It is advised that you do this on a PC.

**1. Export:** You can export contacts from your Mi account to a Vcard (Vcf) file. This can be done by logging into your Mi Account at - https://i.mi.com/

Choose *Export Contacts > Export* and you will get the Vcard file to download.

---

**2. Import:** You can then import those to your Google contacts by logging into your Google account at https://contacts.google.com

Choose *More > Import* at from the left sidebar. Then click on CSV or vCard file and select the Vcard file which you downloaded from Mi contacts.

Your contacts will be imported. For the future, change where to save the contact to "Google account" while adding a new contact.